# Can't remove empty folder

Tags: java, windows, java-8, filesystems

Inside an existing folder, I created a folder and inside it multiple files using this method:

```
SeekableByteChannel createFile(String filePathToCreate) throws IOException {
    OpenOption[] options = {
            StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW,
            StandardOpenOption.SPARSE,
            StandardOpenOption.READ
            // TODO: think if we add CREATE if exist rule.
    };
    return Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get(filePathToCreate), options);
}
```

The folders/files structure is:

```
- torrents-test
   - folder1
       - File-I-Created-1
       - File-I-Created-2
       - File-I-Created-3
```

Then I tried to delete the folder `torrents-test` using this method:

```
void deleteDirectory(File directoryToBeDeleted) throws IOException {
    File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
    if (allContents != null) {
        for (File file : allContents) {
            deleteDirectory(file);
        }
    }
    Files.delete(directoryToBeDeleted.toPath());
}
```

Then I got an exception which tells me that the folder `folder1` is not empty so I can't delete it:

```
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\GIT\university\torrentx\torrents-test\folder1
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
    at com.utils.Utils.deleteDirectory(Utils.java:389)
    at com.utils.Utils.deleteDirectory(Utils.java:386)
    at com.utils.Utils.deleteDownloadFolder(Utils.java:375)
    at com.utils.Utils.removeEverythingRelatedToTorrent(Utils.java:87)
    at com.steps.MyStepdefs.applicationCreateActiveTorrentFor(MyStepdefs.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

My `deleteDirectory` method first remove all the files inside every folder it tries to delete and only then it will remove the folder. The exception indicates the deletion of every file inside that folder was successful because if not, I would get an exception earlier while trying to remove one of that folder's files.

**My question is** - Why do I get that exception?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Do you really think it makes sense to call a method named `deleteDirectory` with the name of a file? You're doing it in the recursive calls.

Comment: @Andreas It was that or `DeleteAllFilesAndFoldersInsideFolder`. I chose the shorter one. But I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why are you mixing old and new APIs? `File` vs `Path`. Instead of recursive call with `File.listFiles()`, use [`Files.walkFileTree(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-).

Comment: *"I'm open to suggestions"* How about ... `delete(File fileOrDir)`. Or better yet, use the newer NIO.2 as make it `delete(Path fileOrDir)`.

Comment: @Andreas using it outside of the class would make it unclear **what** I'm trying to delete.

Comment: Really? The parameter is a `File` (or `Path`), so a method called `delete()` could be confusing how? No one would think it e.g. deletes a database table.

Comment: @Andreas While using `Files.walkFileTree(...)` I'm still getting the same exception *after* successfully removing the files inside that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc of `java.nio.file.Files.delete(Path path)` is clear :

> If the file is a directory then the directory must be empty.

It is also stated :

> This method can be used with the walkFileTree method to delete a
>   directory and all entries in the directory, or an entire file-tree
>   where required.

Using `Files.walkFileTree()` would make your code clearer and shorter but note that it will not solve your actual problem.
Besides your recursive method to delete all resources is correct as you delete resources by starting by the deeper and by go backing up the less deep.

The problem is somewhere else: indeed you are creating the text files with  `Files.newByteChannel()` that creates some `SeekableByteChannel` instances that are connected to the `File`s. Consequently it seems to prevent the files from being deleted on the fly as you invoke         `Files.delete(directoryToBeDeleted.toPath());`.
So close the streams before deleting the files and it should work.

Comment: I must have got exceptions earlier that indicates that the files were not removed.... **But I didn't**.

Comment: If you have this error message it means that the files were not **effectively** removed at the same time where the method is invoked. In fact the problem cause is more subtle. I updated.